# Are there convention for directive parameter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I saw many directives that use a string as a parameter like `ng-repeat`, or `angular-bootstrap`. But it is difficult to validate or extract values from the parameter.

I think that an object literal as a parameter is a better option, but I rarely see any directive that is implemented this way.

I wonder if an object literal as a parameter considered a bad practice. Are their any convention about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no convention about the type of parameters, the ng-class directive for example take an object and it's work fine.

Use a string is more friendly and clean to use, however it's harder to use in the code.
Use an object is sometimes usefull and easier to use than a string but it's harder to read in the view.

Comment: Do you know some techniques or tools for extracting value from string as a parameter?

Comment: I think the best way is to use the same as Angular uses, simply parse the string with a regex